# TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' for some 50% part of the logic where the remaining 50% is working fine

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary which I keep updating based on current/live market data. Below is the dictionary which I mentioned about and below that is the logic to update the dictionary.

The dictionary

```
trd_portfolio = {5633: {"Symbol": "ACC", "max_quantity": 10000, "Direction": "", 'Orderid': 0, 'Target_order': '', 'Target_order_id': 0},
                 25601: {"Symbol": "AMARAJABAT", "max_quantity": 10000, "Direction": "", 'Orderid': 0, 'Target_order': '', 'Target_order_id': 0}
                 }
```

The update logic

```
def order_status(token, orderid, type):
    order_details = kite.order_history(orderid)
    for item in order_details:
        if item['status'] == "COMPLETE":
            if type == 'SELL':
                trd_portfolio[token]['Direction'] = "Down"
                trd_portfolio[token]['Target_order'] = "NO"
                print(trd_portfolio[token]['Direction'], trd_portfolio[token]['Target_order'])
                break
            elif type == 'BUY':
                trd_portfolio[token]['Direction'] = "Up"
                trd_portfolio[token]['Target_order'] = "NO"
                print(trd_portfolio[token]['Direction'], trd_portfolio[token]['Target_order'])
                break
        elif item['status'] == "REJECTED":
            print(trd_portfolio[token]['Direction'], trd_portfolio[token]['Target_order'])
            break
    else:
        time.sleep(1)
        order_status(token, orderid, type)
```

If I call the update logic method with the values as `order_status(5633, some_order_id, SELL)`, the dictionary is getting updated properly and I am able to proceed. But if I am calling the method as `order_status(5633, some_order_id, BUY)`, it gives me the below error.

```
trd_portfolio[token]['Direction'] = "Up"
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Why is it failing at one place and working at another, I don't see any difference in it. Why does it have to be hashable, as I would want to keep updating the dictionary throughout the day.

Comment: Can you give an example on how you call the function?

Comment: Looks like at some point, token becomes a dict so it can't be used to index a dict.

Answer (score 0):

How do you ever know that two objects are equal or not?

This is important. If we write,

```
d[3] = 0
d[3] = 99

d[1] = 5
d[2] = 104
```

Then, the `99` is supposed to replace the `0`. This is because `3 == 3`. But, `104` is not supposed to replace the `5` because `1 != 2`. But, how does the computer know whether dictionary keys are equal to each-other or not?

Consider the following code:

```
x = "apple"
y = "apple"
print(x == y)
```

The output is `True`. But how did the computer know that the two strings were equal? Well, it converted the strings into numbers, and then compared the numbers for equality. See below:

```
x = "apple"
y = "apple"
x_number = hash(x)
y_number = hash(y)
print(x_number)
print(y_number)
```

The output is:

```
1505705734
1505705734
```

Suppose that you write your own class:

```
class XYCoodinate:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

How does the computer know if two instances are equal? The computer does not know what it means for two `XYCoodinates` to be equal unless you tell it.

```
xy1 = XYCoodinate(1, 2)
xy2 = XYCoodinate(1, 2)
print(xy1 == xy2)
```

Even though the two `XYCoodinate`s look pretty equal to a human, the output of the equality test is `False`. The computer honestly does not know what to do. As such the default behavior is the following:

```
def __eq__(lhs, rhs):
    # `lhs`...........`left-hand-side`
    # `rhs`...........`right-hand-side`
if `lhs` and `rhs` are two different labels for the same memory "hotel room"
    # if a hotel room contains 5 it contains 5, not both 2 and 5.
    # if you have two different names for the same hotel room, they must be equal
    return True
if `lhs` and `rhs` are two different memory "hotel room" numbers:
    # the hotel rooms might contain two copies the same data, the hotel rooms might not
    # However, unless it's something simply like an integer,
    # the computer doesn't know how to tell if they are equal or not.
```

The computer knows how to hash integers, and tuples of integers, so let's do that:

```
class XYCoordinate:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(tuple([self.x, self.y]))
    def __eq__(lhs, rhs):
        return hash(lhs) == hash(rhs)

xy1 = XYCoordinate(1, 2)
xy2 = XYCoordinate(1, 2)
print(hash(xy1))
print(hash(xy2))
print(xy1 == xy2)
```

The output is:

```
994727857
994727857
True
```

When you use something as a dictionary key, the dictionary uses the hash value. `dct[xy1] = "apple"` is **almost** the same as `dct[hash(xy1)] = "apple"`

What if the object having hash value `994727857` ***changes*** sometime later? That would be very very bad.

class XYCoordinate:
    def **init**(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def **hash**(self):
        return hash(tuple([self.x, self.y]))
    def **eq**(lhs, rhs):
        return hash(lhs) == hash(rhs)
    def **str**(self):
        return str(tuple([self.x, self.y]))
    def **repr**(self):
        return str(self)

```
d = dict()
xy1 = XYCoordinate(1, 2)
xy2 = XYCoordinate(3, 4)
d[xy1] = "apple"
d[xy2] = "banana"
print(d) 
# {(1, 2): 'apple', (3, 4): 'banana'}

# change `xy2` to be the "same" as xy1
xy2.x = xy1.x
xy2.y = xy1.y
print(xy2) # prints (1, 2)
# d[(1, 2)] = "orange"
d[xy2] = "orange"
print(d) 
# {(1, 2): 'orange', (1, 2): 'banana'}
```

After looking at the above, I hope you're asking yourself, "What the heck happened? How is the final dictionary `{(1, 2): 'orange', (1, 2): 'banana'}`?"

Things used as dictionary keys are supposed to ***never*** change.

```
d[key] = 5

# key does not change
# key does not change
# [... a long time later]
# key does not change
# key does not change

d[key] = 99
```

You got an error because you tried to use a dictionary (`token`) as a key to another dictionary.

```
key_ab = {1:"apple"      2:"banana"}
key_cd = {1:"cantaloupe", 2:"date" }

d = dict()
d[key_ab] = 4
d[key_cd] = 99

# key not supposed to change!
key_cd = {1:"apple", 2:"banana" }

d[key_cd] = 104
```

Whatever you use as dictionary keys, make sure that they are ***constant***. The number 4 never changes. You can change which number is in the hotel room with "`x`" written on the door, but you cannot change the number 4.

Likewise, you can change which string is staying in which hotel room, but in python, the string "apple" will be "apple" for all eternity.

You can use integers, strings, tuples of integers, tuples of strings, frozensets, and a few other things for dictionary ***keys***. The ***values*** are supposed to be able to change, just not the ***keys***. You can also use anything you define a `__hash__` method for, but only do that if you can be extra-special-super-duper certain that the object will never-ever change after you call `hash` for the first time.